# How to get more target platform options for Eclipse AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Using Eclipse, trying to create a new virtual device to test app on older Android versions, but when I go to create a new Android Virtual Device I only get one option - 4.4.2 API Level 19.   How do I get other versions to show here? Last night I was a bit tired and tried to if using the SDK Manager to grab 4.0.3 SDK and Google API would work to test on older version, but it seemed to mess up Eclipse as I got an ADT needs update error (which would find no updates). So starting back from scratch and figured I'd ask instead of trial and error.  Thanks!

Comment: You're doing the right thing installing another SDK version through the SDK Manager, that should be all that's required. Try launching it directly rather than through Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, seemed to work this time. Not sure what on earth I ended up doing last night..

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SD Manager, check Show: Updates/New

Select SDK Platform and ARM EABI v7a System Image (also Google APIs if you are unsing them) for all Versions you want to test and download them. You need the source of the Android-Version to create an AVD for it.

Updating your Android SDK build-tools and Android SDK Platform-tools is always recommanded because newer Android versions need a newer build tool setup.